# Problem in PL/SQL = Error Stack: ORA-01403: No Data in Oracle Application Express (APEX)

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've created an upload system with web services (uploading to Oracle bucket). I've copied the pages and webservices to my new app(from an already working app) but i'm having problems with the uploading function. The error i'm getting is ORA-01403: No Data, in the original page there is no problem and everything is working fine. Can someone please help me with this problem or send me in the good direction.

PL/SQL code

```
begin declare
  l_request_url varchar2(32767);    
  l_content_length number;    
  l_response clob;    
  upload_failed_exception exception;    
begin    
  for file in (    
  select * from apex_application_temp_files    
  where name = :P101_FILE    
  ) loop    
  l_request_url := :G_BASE_URL || 'b/##BUCKETNAME##'    
  || '/o/' || apex_util.url_encode(file.filename);    
    
  apex_debug.info('File: %s', file.filename);    
  apex_debug.info('URL: %s', l_request_url);    
  apex_debug.info('Mime: %s', file.mime_type);    
    
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name :=    
  'Content-Type';    
  apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value :=    
  file.mime_type;    
  l_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(    
  p_url => l_request_url    
  , p_http_method => 'PUT'    
  , p_body_blob => file.blob_content    
  , p_credential_static_id => :G_OCI_WEB_CREDENTIAL    
  );    
  if apex_web_service.g_status_code != 200 then    
  raise upload_failed_exception;    
  end if;    
  end loop;    
end;  
end;
```

P101_FILE = a upload file item

##BUCKETNAME## = inthe original code is the actual name of the bucket.

Debug:

```
Exception in "plsql process":  
Error Stack: ORA-01403: Geen gegevens gevonden.  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1594  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2658  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_CREDENTIAL", regel 106  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 376  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 416  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", regel 2120  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", regel 590  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2621  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1568  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_LOCAL", regel 2761  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3775  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3810  
Backtrace: ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_CREDENTIAL", regel 106  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 376  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 416  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", regel 2120  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", regel 590  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2621  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1594  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2658  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_CREDENTIAL", regel 106  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 376  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 416  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", regel 2120  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", regel 590  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2621  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1568  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_LOCAL", regel 2761  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3775  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3810  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 76  
2  
1%  
0.04179 0.00030  
Exception in "uploadFile":  
Error Stack: ORA-01403: Geen gegevens gevonden.  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 96  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1594  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2658  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_CREDENTIAL", regel 106  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 376  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 416  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", regel 2120  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", regel 590  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2621  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1568  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_LOCAL", regel 2761  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3775  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3810  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 76  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 1156  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100~  
Backtrace: ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_CREDENTIAL", regel 106  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 376  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 416  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", regel 2120  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", regel 590  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2621  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 96  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1594  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2658  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_CREDENTIAL", regel 106  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 376  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", regel 416  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in regel 22  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", regel 2120  
ORA-06512: in "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", regel 590  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 2621  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", regel 1568  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC_LOCAL", regel 2761  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3775  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_EXEC", regel 3810  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 76  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", regel 1156  
ORA-06512: in "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", regel 2586  
ORA-0~  
2  
1%  
0.04209 0.00065  
Add error onto error stack  
4  
1%  
0.04273 0.00020  
Hiding error additional_info, as it contains ORA error message: ORA-01403: Geen gegevens gevonden.  
1  
0%  
0.04293 0.00002  
Error: ORA-01403: Geen gegevens gevonden
```

Comment: you are getting NO DATA FOUND and only can be in the `select * from apex_application_temp_files  where name = :P101_FILE` Use the APEX SQL Workshop and check whether you have data in that table

Comment: also check if the `:P101_FILE` is the actual name of the element in the apex page

Comment: Does :g_base_url and :g_oci_web_credential has proper value assigned ? From where the "Exception in "uploadFile" this is raising ?

Comment: apex_application_temp_files is the temporary storage of the P101_FILE file-upload item. In DEBUG i'm getting all the info (filename/mime type and  the constructed URL).

Comment: The substitutions are exactly the same in both applications. The URL(l_request_url) is constructed just the way it should be.

Comment: P101_FILE is the right name of the item. The strange situation is that all items, pages and substitutions are exact copies of the working original application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a space in the substitution of :G_OCI_WEB_CREDENTIAL. After deleting the space, everything is working fine. Thanks for the help!